# Xamarin forms SQLite Spatial Data dlopen failed

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, spatial

In my project I have **spatial database with Entity framework.**

When execute `dbContext.Database.Migrate()`  I get this error

> Unhandled Exception:Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite
>   Error 1: 'dlopen failed: library "mod_spatialite.so" not found'.

I tried with adding mod_spatialite from nuget still error is coming.

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is the mod_spatialite.so version 4.3.0.1? After adding mod_spatialite from nuget, did you try to clean the solution, then run it. You could delete the obj and bin folder as well, then build solution.If this error is still existed.

Comment: Yes @LeonLu-MSFT. I added mod_spatialite from nuget, clean the solution and build again it show the same error. I tried closing visual studio & reopening also.

Comment: Any news on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there any update to this issue?